# explain to me how this path works and what these error messages mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here is the route:

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'photos#index', as: :tag
```

which gives url www.example.com/tags/food

I figured out that the correct path is

```
<%= link_to 'Food', tag_path(:tag => "food") %>
```

1. why do i have to put quotations around food, turning it into a string?
2. why does `tag_path(tag: "food")` return the error:

> (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/tags/food":String):

if i just do `tag_path(tag: food)` i get an error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `food'

3. is it actually possible to pass a method from the controller into the path? that sounds cool. can you give me an example of such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tag_path('food')`, `tag_path(tag: food)` tries to use the variable food which does not exists.

3. Yes that's possible, you can use `tag_path(current_user)` but then you are passing in the return value of the method.